# django view called twice

Tags: python, django, view, web

Sorry for my bad English, I'll try to describe my problem as best I can.
I'm using Django 1.5 with Python 3.2. I'm using django.contrib.messages for showing messages to users after redirecting them. If I try and load the page that redirects to another page which shows a message, after several tries it doesn't delete previous messages (only of the last previous page). And so, what I see is 2 identical messages. This happens only in Google Chrome (and Cromium). Never in FireFox or Opera. Regardless of whether the messages being saved as cookies or in session.
The view function is being called twice, but I don't know why and what Chrome in particular has to do with it(???).

I've recorded video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nXtQ0uj1Hbw&feature=youtu.be.

Added later...

Ok. I've started a new project just for this (project "mysite" containing one application inside it called "test_app"):

contents of mysite/urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^ms', include('test_app.urls', namespace="testapp")),
)
```

contents of test_app.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url


urlpatterns = patterns('test_app.views',
    url(r'/go-away/$', 'go_away', name='go-away'),
    url(r'/come-here/$', 'come_here', name='come-here'),
)
```

contents of test_app/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.contrib import messages

import random

def go_away(request):

    messages.info(request, 'FORBIDDEN PLACE! Float: %f' % random.random())
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('testapp:come-here'))

def come_here(request):
    return render(request, 'testapp/template.html', {})
```

contents of testapp/templates/testapp/template.html

```
{% if messages %}
    <ul>
        {% for message in messages %}
            <li>{{ message }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    There was no redirection.
{% endif %}
```

apart from all of that, i added into my settings.py (at the and):

```
# Context processors
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = {
   'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
}
```

configured database (mysite/mysite.db) and even ran the command "python3 manage.py syncdb"

Nothing else was done. You can reproduce that easily.

My software:
 - Python 3.2
 - Django 1.5
 - Apache 2.2 with MOD_WSGI compiled from source.
 - All this under Linux Mint 14.

What you should see in the end:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3L27iwP1PqM&feature=youtu.be
quality is not the gratest, but i did paste the code here.

As you can see, the floats are all different, that means that the messages are added during only one request and do not show themselves on any other pages. And that means, as I can understand, that the view function was run twice, ignoring first redirect.

P.S.: It is the same with session, if you save you messages manually into the request.session.messages list.
I have such a problem only when I use Chrome or Chromium. Opera, as you can see, works perfectly.

Comment: Without code how can we tell you where is problem?

Comment: Post code of urls, views and from where you are redirecting.

Comment: Please post your code, and your English is great.

Comment: @user2626972 Have you solved this? I have exactly same problem.

Answer (score 3):

Google Chrome sends a request when you type the url. So, when you hit enter, it sends another request. The problem you are having is probably because the time between typing the url and pressing enter is very short.

You could perhaps implement a time-based view [like](http://julienphalip.com/post/2823667856/testing-time-based-views-in-django) this to circumvent the problem.

Answer (score 2):

It's this line that calls your views twice:

> return render(request, 'testapp/template.html', {})

I have run into the same problem...I printed all the ***request*** and checked logs of ***manage.py*** and found that 
[render calls views two more times for css files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aL5au.png)

In order to avoid this, I called another function to handle data.
Of course, you can add

> if request.method=='POST':

to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Privet!
Try to run app at not built in django webserver. I don't know, but maybe, u refresh page very often and biult in webserver don't have time to complete previous response.

Comment: i'm running my applications under apache 2.2, MOD_WSGI 3.4, Python 3.2, Linux Mint 14 64 bit.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, except that I'm using Django 1.6, Python 2.7 and I see this issue also in non-Chrome browsers (Firefox).

I have discovered connection between this issue and `CACHES` [settings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/#caches):

Try to set on your production server (Apache):

```py
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.dummy.DummyCache',
    }
}
```

And make sure you have configured `SESSION_ENGINE`:

```py
SESSION_ENGINE = 'django.contrib.sessions.backends.db'
```

In my case, the problem occurs only when `CACHES` is set to "real cache" like `MemcachedCache` or `LocMemCache` (default value if this variable is not set) etc.